# setInterval() with fresh database data?

Tags: node.js, express

Hello and thank you in advance for taking your time to help me,

I've a setInterval() script who change some data in my MongoDB.
For example:

```
const isOn = mySavedDatabase.isOn;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  fetch('https://thewebsite.com', options)
   .then(res => {
     return res.json();
   }).then(async data => {
       if(data.data[0] && isOn == false) {

         await xx.updateMe(xxx.id, { "isOn": true });
         // some others actions here
         
       } else if(isOn && !data.data[0]) {
         await xx.updateMe(xxx.id, { "isOn": false });
       } else if(isOn && data.data[0]) {
         // nothing to do here.
       }
     })
}, 60000);
```

This script works fine, but it does not take the new changed data from the database.
If in the database, when the script starts, the value of "**isOn**" is **true**, it will remain true until the end of the script even if, in this one, I changed the data.

I checked, the value is changed by the **setInterval()** but, as long as it is in the loop, it does not take data from the database that it itself has changed.

Currently, for setInterval() work, I have to add each time :

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

But, it does not respect the time of one minute that I put and it sends way more requests than 1 per minute.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-evaluate `mySavedDatabase.isOn`
I would just remove constant `isOn`, and use `mySavedDatabase.isOn` instaed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've already tried and it does not work.

This executes the first condition each time.

Comment: Is perhaps your if condition inverted? it updates if data.data[0] is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Just pass the:

```
const isOn = mySavedDatabase.isOn;
```

In the **setInterval()** to get fresh data.